# Render a webform to another node

Tags: nodes, blocks, theming

I have a new text format sample_page with the filter sample_page, I've created using hook_filter_info(). In the callback, I am rendering a webform using depending on the token in the node body, for webform I'm planning to use a token [block:webform:webform-client-form-2423].

I could render the blocks created programmatically, system blocks. But not the blocks created by other modules, I have tried [block:user:login] from http://mine.local/admin/structure/block/manage/user/login/configure to render to login blocks too. But these blocks didnt seems to work. Here is my callback for filter.

System blocks that worked for me, I used the token [block:block:25] from http://mine.local/admin/structure/block/manage/block/2/configure and for blocks created programatically by my own module, suppose my module is my_module,
I have used the token [block:my_module:block_name] from the url http://mine.local/admin/structure/block/manage/my_module/block_name/configure

```
preg_match_all('/\\[([a-zA-z0-9_\-]+:[a-zA-z0-9_\-]+)+\\]/m', $text, $match);
$matches = $match[0];
foreach ($matches as $token) {
  $token_name = str_replace(array( '[', ']' ), '', $token);
  $type = explode(':', $token_name);
  if ($type[0] == 'block') {
    $module = $type[1];
    $bid = $type[2];
    $block = block_load($module, $bid);
    $replacement = render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)))); 
  }
}
```

Can any one look into the problem. Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Would something like 'Nodes in Block' work for you.   https://www.drupal.org/project/nodesinblock

Answer (score 1):

You can add the webform using hook_page_alter().

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_alter().
 */
function my_module_page_alter(&$page){

  // Get the webform's nid that you want to display on the current page.
  $webform_nid = my_module_webform_to_display();

  // Load the webform node.
  $webform = node_load($webform_nid);

  // Render the webform using my custom view mode.
  $markup = drupal_render(node_view($webform, 'my_custom_view_mode'));

  // Add the markup to the page element.
  $page['content']['system_main'][] = array(
    '#markup' => $markup,
  );
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if could add it using https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.api.php/function/hook_filter_info/7. Also I wanted to handle/ render the blocks by other modules.